# What is the best practice for throwing exceptions inside an Akka Stream - Scala?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am new to Akka Stream and trying to figure out what is the best practice for handling unexpected behaviors inside a stream.

I am building a stream which uses [Account Kit API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi) to exchange short-term code to a long-live access token.

Here is the relevant code for building the stream:

```
override def ExchangeCode: Flow[String, AccessTokenInfo, NotUsed] =
Flow[String].mapAsync(1) { code =>
  ws.url(buildUrl("access_token"))
    .withQueryString(
      "grant_type" -> "authorization_code",
      "code" -> code,
      "access_token" -> appToken
    )
    .withRequestTimeout(timeout)
    .get
    .map { response =>
      if (response.status != 200) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected response")
      else response.json
    }
    .map { json =>
      AccessTokenInfo("123456", 123, "123456")
    }
}
```

I wonder if throwing an exception if status code is not 200 is the right way to deal with it, but this is the only way of terminating a stream ahead of time as I know it. (Currently the return value is a dummy one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is it a strict necessity that the stream terminate if the status is not 200?  Usually you want to send even the failures downstream so any user of the `Flow` can be informed and act accordingly.

The typical way of dealing with this type of failure is with [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.Try).  Slightly modifying your Flow:

```
//                                  Add Try Output
//                                       |
//                                       v
override def ExchangeCode: Flow[String, Try[AccessTokenInfo], _] = 
  Flow[String] 
    ...
    .map { response => response.status match {
        case 200 => Try { response.json }
        case _   => Try { throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected Response") }
      }
    }
    .map( _ map (json => AccessTokenInfo("123456", 123, "123456")))
```

Now any user of the flow can get the valid access token if it was possible to retrieve or get the Exception and be able to handle the failure case.

**Alternative Return Type: Option**

If there is only 1 Exception that can be generated by only 1 cause then an `Option` is a viable return type as well:

```
override def ExchangeCode: Flow[String, Option[AccessTokenInfo], _] = 
  ...
        case 200 => Some(response.json)
        case _   => None
  ...
```